# Why does pyinstaller create so large exe files?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

While I was converting my python game file to exe file using *pyinstaller*, the size came out to be very large(300 MB). I also had used upx which made file exe file even more large(317 MB). The python game file is an offline game. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).   Maybe you want to ask this question at [superusers](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: No, there is no solution. Wrapping a Python program is more complex than you seem to imagine. `pyinstaller` takes the bytecode of your program, and of every module it imports, and every module *they* import, and every binary extension (`.so` or DLL) they need, and a copy of the Python interpreter, and puts them all in a huge `.exe`. There is no way around this because Python is not a compiled language, so there is no way to represent your program directly in machine code.

Comment: 1. because it bundles everything, including python interpreter, into one self-contained executable; 2. The solution is not using py"installer", it bloats everything for no real benefit, and is just another 3rd party library that you need to expect to work, except it doesn't work, it can't even cross-"compile", that's how terrible it is. You don't make an executable, you provide the original source code in a form of a package and user can use it. [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Comment: what is the best way to provide game executable to someone else without sharing the code. @Kaihaku

Comment: @GarvPuri to not use CPython.

Comment: There is a solution which is to explicitly exclude packages that PyInstaller pulls in to ensure it satisfies every dependency even ones you know you don’t use (but it has no way of knowing that). Examine the output from PyInstaller build process looking for packages you know you don’t need. I’ve found `tqdm` is particularly needy in this respect.

Comment: It would probably worth using a virtual environment to build your executable so you can only install the modules that are strictly required for your game. See the docs for [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pygame is optionally dependent on numpy, scipy, and PIL. (Or maybe the scipy and PIL come from being optionally dependent on numpy, it makes no difference here)

If you have those installed on your system, PyInstaller will bundle them with your executable. But you probably don't need them. (Unless you're using `pygame.sndarray` or `pygame.surfarray`, which are backed by numpy).

To exclude them, you can add the following to the `excludes` portion of your `.spec` file: `['numpy', 'scipy', 'PIL']`

It looks like you could also do this as a command line option with multiple uses of the `--exclude-module` argument. See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-exclude-module

Some people also get around this by using virtual environments.

But even assuming you have those 3 libraries bundled, 300 mb is quite large. If you're doing onefile mode, stop doing that for debugging, so you can see the folder names and files included with your project. That will give you more insight.